# Continuous function with compact domain has continuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $A,B\subset\mathbb R$ and $f:A\to B$ be an invertible function (so 1-1 and onto). Prove that if $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then the inverse $f^{-1}:B\to A$ is continuous. And give a counterexample when $A$ is not compact (no transcendentals).

If $f$ is continuous, then for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ that converges to $L$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(L)$. We need to prove that for every sequence $\{y_n\}$ in $B$ that converges to $K$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{-1}(y_n)=f^{-1}(K)$ (Is this sufficient to prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?), I'm not sure how to proceed from there, and I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample as well.

Comment: Do you know the following two statements? 1. The image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact. 2. A function is continuous if and only if for every open set in the codomain, its pre-image is open. // Your assumptions plus statement 1 implies that $f$ is an open map. So using 2 you have that its inverse function is coninuous.

Comment: @Willie Wong No I have neither of those statements

Comment: What statements do you have at your disposal? Do you have Heine-Borel theorem? What is your operating definition of continuity and compactness?

Comment: @Willie Wong Yes I have Heine-Borel theorem for compactness, continuity is the normal $\varepsilon, \delta$

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, the most expeditious way to prove this is to use

> $f$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if for any open set $V \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $X$.

where $X$ and $Y$ are domain and codomain of $f$ (can be arbitrary metric space).

Based on this statement, to show $f^{-1}$ is a continuous mapping of $B$ onto $A$, it is sufficient to show that for any open set $V \subset A$, $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $B$, that is, $f(V)$ is open in $B$.

Now since $V$ is open in $A$ and $A$ is compact, $V^c \cap A$, as a closed subset of $A$, is compact (use the theorem that any closed subset of a compact set is compact). Since $f$ is continuous, $f(V^c \cap A)$ is compact and so is closed in $B$ (use the theorem that continuous mapping of any compact set is compact). Now since $f$ is one-to-one and onto, $f(V)$ is the complement of $f(V^c \cap A)$, hence is open in $B$.

---

For the counterexample, consider $A = [0, 1] \cup (2, 3]$, which is not compact, and define $f$ as follows:
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x \in [0, 1] \\
x - 1 & x \in (2, 3] 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$f$ is a one-to-one and onto function of $A$ to $B = [0, 2]$, in addition, $f$ is continuous at every point of $A$. It is easily to get that
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x \in [0, 1] \\
x + 1 & x \in (1, 2] 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Hence $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $1$! (a jump occurs here).

Comment: How do I use the statement to prove my statement?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that last step, why if $f(V)$ the complement of $f(V^c\cap A)$?

Comment: Because $V \cap (V^c \cap A) = \varnothing$, so $f(V) \cap f(V^c \cap A) = \varnothing$, by the injectivity of $f$. The fact that $f(V) \cup f(V^c \cap A)  = B$ is obvious by surjectivity.

Comment: @Solitary: mind that the OP claimed he is not aware of the theorem stating continuous maps compact to compact http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523622/continuous-function-with-compact-domain-has-continuous-inverse/1523638?noredirect=1#comment3102594_1523622

Comment: @WillieWong I understand, but OP asked me in the comment. The main point of my post is to give the counterexample, not the proof.

Comment: @Solitary Why not use closed sets instead..?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter How would you use closed sets instead?

Comment: @BCho Another characterization of continuity is that a continuous function pullsback closed sets to closed sets

Comment: @Anthony Peter What does pulling back mean and how does that apply here?

Comment: @BCho just a different way of saying inverse image of... he used that inverse images of open sets are open, but you could also use that inverse images of closed sets are closed

Comment: @AnthonyPeter: I suspect the real reason is that there is a higher chance "random math student" remember the open set version than the closed set version, especially if he/she has taken a standard course in point set topology. But a facetious answer could be [sometimes it just makes more sense to use open sets](http://mathoverflow.net/a/85638/3948)

Answer (score 5):

What you have:

- $f$ is bijective $A\to B$
- $\forall x\in A ~\forall \epsilon > 0 ~\exists \delta > 0 ~\forall x' \in A (|x - x'| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x') | < \epsilon)$.

What you want:

- $\forall x \in A~ \forall \epsilon > 0 ~\exists \delta > 0 ~\forall x' \in A (|f(x) - f(x')| < \delta \implies |x - x'| < \epsilon)$.

Proof by contradiction (sketch): assume for contradiction

$$ \exists x\in A ~ \exists \epsilon > 0 ~\forall \delta > 0 ~\exists x' \in A ~(|f(x) - f(x')| < \delta ~\wedge ~ |x - x'| \geq \epsilon )$$

Then letting $\delta_k = \frac{1}{k}$ we can find a sequence $\{x_k\}$ such that $|f(x) - f(x_k)| < 1/k$ while $|x - x_k| \geq \epsilon$.

By the Heine-Borel we have that $A$ is bounded. By Bolzano-Weierstrass we have that $\{x_k\}$ has a converging subsequence which we call $\{y_k\}$. Since $A$ is closed the limit, which we call $y$, is in $A$.

Since $f$ is continuous and $y_k \to y$ you have $f(y_k) \to f(y)$. On the other hand since by assumption $f(x_k) \to f(x)$, the subsequence $f(y_k)$ must also converge to $f(x)$. This implies $f(x) = f(y)$. But we know that $|y - x| \geq \epsilon$ by triangle inequality and so $y \neq x$. This contradicts injectivity.

---

I am assuming since you already have Heine-Borel you also have Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: Why does $|y-x|\geq \varepsilon$?

Comment: $|y-x| - |y - x'| \geq |x - x'|$ by triangle inequality. Sub in $y_k$ for $x'$ and note $y - y_k \to 0$.

Comment: Can you sub in a sequence for an element?

Comment: doesn't $|x-x'|$ also go to 0?

Comment: Of course not. $\forall k$ we have $|x - x_k| \geq \epsilon$ by assumption.

Comment: Wrong inequality.