# When defining arclength of a curve, does it matter whether the partition norm approaches $0$ in the domain (interval) or the codomain (space)?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, curves, arc-length, partitions-for-integration

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^d$ is continuous, and $P=[t_0,t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_{n-1},t_n]$ is a partition, so $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=1$. Define

$$\sum_P\lVert df\rVert=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\lVert f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\rVert,$$
$$|P|=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(t_i-t_{i-1}),$$
$$|f(P)|=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\lVert f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\rVert.$$

We consider three definitions of the length of the curve $f$ (the letter $D$ is for "domain", and $C$ for "codomain"):

$$S=\sup_P\sum_P\lVert df\rVert,$$
$$D=\lim_{|P|\to0}\sum_P\lVert df\rVert,$$
$$C=\lim_{|f(P)|\to0}\sum_P\lVert df\rVert.$$

The [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820429/prove-equivalence-of-two-definitions-of-arclength-for-non-differentiable-curves?noredirect=1) shows that $S=D$. (In fact it's true even when one of them is infinite.) Now I want to know whether $D=C$.

By uniform continuity of $f$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for all partitions $P$, if $|P|\leq\delta$ then $|f(P)|\leq\varepsilon$.

Suppose $C$ exists. So for any $\eta>0$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all partitions $P$, if $|f(P)|\leq\varepsilon$ then $|\sum_P\lVert df\rVert-C|\leq\eta$. Combining this with uniform continuity, we find that $D$ exists and $D=C$.

Similarly, if $C$ is infinite then $D$ is infinite.

Does this exhaust all the possibilities? Must $C$ exist in $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$?

Suppose the curve is closed, $f(0)=f(1)$, but not constant (not just a point), so its length $S=D$ is positive. Considering the trivial partition $P=[0,1]$, both $0$ and $D$ are limit points of the sums (as $|f(P)|\to0$), so $C$ doesn't exist. To avoid this, let's assume that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, the image of $f$ is also compact. Since $f$ is injective, it has an inverse.

We can use this: [Continuous function with compact domain has continuous inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523622/continuous-function-with-compact-domain-has-continuous-inverse), to find that $f^{-1}$ is continuous (hence uniformly).

Then the argument for $C\implies D$ is easily modified for $D\implies C$.